# make <a> link not performing the default function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `<a href="someaddress">` link that also has a `onclick` function under a parent `<div>` with id of "mention". How can I make it so that by default, when user clicks the `<a>` link it will not redirect to the webpage but it will do the onclick function?

I want to still have href because in case if user's javascript doesn't work, at least they can still go to the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onclick="return false;"` is a way to make an `<a>` tag not actually do anything on click.

### EDIT

i had `onlick`, obv. it was supposed to be `onclick`

Answer (score 6):

...or `return false;` on your javascript call.

Answer (score 5):

insert e.preventDefault() into your onclick function if it already exists, e.g.

```
$("#mention a").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // whatever is not default
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also use `return false;`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `event.preventDefault()`.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/FishBasketGordo/2R2Ud/.